# How do I check if an element exists inside a jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-plugins, turbolinks

My question is pretty self explanatory - I'm writing a jQuery plugin where the user specifies a selector. I need to check if that selector exists, and if so, execute some code. However, I can't figure out how to do that check inside of my jQuery plugin.

I need to do this because I'm trying to create something like jquery-readyselector (https://github.com/Verba/jquery-readyselector) that works with Turbolinks.

I want to be able to use the function like so:

```
$("#mySelector").pageReady(function() {
    // This is only triggered if #mySelector exists.
    console.log('test')
});
```

Here's my attempt:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.pageReady = function(fn) {
    var that = this;
    $(document).on('ready page:load', function() {
      if (that.length <= 0){
        return
      } else {
        fn();
      }
    });
  } 
})(jQuery);
```

The issue with this is that that.length == 0, even if the element exists.

I also tried defining the function inside a 'ready page:load' but I get pageReady is not a function:

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function() {
  $.fn.pageReady = function(fn) {
    if (this.length <= 0) {
      return
    } else {
      fn();
    }
  }
});
```

Note that I'm using Turbolinks with Rails, and that's why I have that `$(document).on('ready page:load' ...)`. Replacing that line with `$(document).ready(...)` would do the same thing in a non-Rails/Turbolinks app.

Comment: whats wrong with what you already have?

Comment: @BenG Sorry! I should have included that. I've updated the OP - basically that.length is always 0, even if the element exists.

Comment: When i tested it in the answer snippet tool, it worked fine.

Comment: @BenG How would I reproduce your test? Where's the answer snippet tool?

Comment: Any luck with this, I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was absolutely mystified that the length of the id could be zero even it was on the page. I checked the source code and the id was there! It turned out that I was testing

```
$('mySelector').length > 1
```

rather than

```
$('#mySelector').length > 1
```

i.e. I left out the `#`.  I know that the above question does not have this mistake, but I note that the BenG tested question in a snippet tool and it worked, so maybe the original code had left out the `#`.  In any case, I imagine that other people will make this same mistake, so this answer should be useful for them.